# Directly access DAO from Java templates

Tags: java, templates, jsp, freemarker

Is it possible to somehow directly access DAO from Java templates? I would like to achieve something like

```
 <#foreach value="eventsDao.getEvents()" as="event">
    <= value="event.getName()" />
 </#foreach>
```

I feel like writing everything to controllers and then to templates is just unnecessary and limiting duplicity.

Also, what are the significant differences between JSP, Freemarker and Apache Tiles? Do they allow this?

Comment: There's a reason things are split up into controller/dao/view layers; having these kinds of dependencies in the view is usually a bad idea for maintainability. In an ideal world you'd only pass a `Map` to the view, so that there would be only the shallowest of dependencies between layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this, breaking the Model-View separation... there are ways. In JSP, you have the `<%! ... %>` and `<% ... %>` blocks in which you can enter Java code. In FreeMarker, while you can't insert Java blocks, you can still call the public methods of objects and classes. Calling the static methods is a bit tricky, because you can't just access classes by name on the language level, but has to put something into the context (the so called data-model) of the template that can do that (see: http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_misc_beanwrapper.html#autoid_55 "Accessing static methods"). Tiles is, I believe, irrelevant in this question.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the JSP, FreeMarker, Tiles question: Tiles is a view compositing framework and unrelated to JSP and FreeMarker aside from being able to use either as templates.

Hopefully it's obvious what the differences between JSP and FreeMarker are, but in a nutshell, FM has a more-concise syntax for typical view constructs like looping, and allows more-direct access to functions without having to define and expose functions the JSP way.

Regarding the "waste" of MVC: sure, you can do everything in the view layer--there's nothing preventing you from writing poorly-architected systems, and for small apps, it likely doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [Pebble](http://www.mitchellbosecke.com/pebble) and it has a pretty clean syntax as well; it would look like the following:

```
{% for event in eventsDao.events %}
  {{ event.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Beyond that, I would also recommend Pebble over Velocity or Freemarker primarily because of Pebble's best feature which is [template inheritance](http://mitchellbosecke.com/pebble/documentation/tag/extends).

Disclaimer: I'm the main author of Pebble